# How to combine two conditional statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Okay i know this is a newb question, but how would i go about only performing IF 2 if IF 1 (text: test appears in data string.) I've tried combining the two but end up with all sorts of issues. So if test doesnt show up the loops skipped, if it does then the regex code i have in IF 2 will be ran.

```
$data = 'hello world "this is a test" last test';


// IF 1 
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
}


// IF 2
if (preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
$quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
$data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
}

echo $data;
```

Comment: Have you tried logical operators, specifically `&&` ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: That wouldnt work because the regex is always true, i need to only perform the regex match if the text test is found.

Comment: actually, it still works. The computer is smart, and only tries the regex if the first check fails. It's called short-circuit evaluation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_evaluation

Comment: Within "if ( a && b )", if a fails, b won't run.

Comment: @Tesserex Ahhh, i should of stuck with it then, thanks for the clarification, ill know better next time. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either:

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
    if (preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
        $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
        $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false && preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
    $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
    $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
}
```

Both do the same thing.
The `&&` operator means "and".
The `||` operator means "or".

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean you want to nest one inside the other?

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false)
{

  if (preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs))
  {
     $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
     $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
  }

}
```

You could also change this to use `&&` (which means "And"):

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false && preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
            $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
            $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
}
```

Also, your code uses `!==`. Is that what you meant or did you mean `!=`? I believe they have different meanings - I know that `!=` means "Not equal" but I'm not sure about `!==`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply nest your IF statements

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
    if (preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
        $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
        $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
    }

}
```

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Saying "I've tried combining the two but end up with all sorts of issues" is quite vague. Combining how? Nested like this? What issues?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (stripos($data, 'test') !== false) {
  if (preg_match('/"[^"]*"/i', $data, $regs)) {
  $quote = str_word_count($regs[0], 1);
  $data = str_replace($regs[0], '"'.implode(' ', $quote).'"', $data);
  }
}
```