# How Can I Combine two Arguments Using If Statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, default-arguments

I really need your help here. I'd like to know how I can use two arguments greater than(>) and less than (<) in a single if statement. I was trying to do this in my code below, but I keep on getting an error message on the 'else' statement.

```
<?php

$value1="7";
if($value1<78);
if($value1>7);
{print"Yes, the answer is above 7 but below 78";} 

else 

{print"that's not correct";}


?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two IF statements in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955678/how-to-combine-two-if-statements-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&`:

```
if($value1 < 78 && $value1 > 7){
    print"Yes, the answer is above 7 but below 78";
} 
else {
    print"that's not correct";
}
```

See: [Control Structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: thanks John, it worked!!. Sorry I can't vote up for now, don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$value1="7";
if($value1<78 && $value1>7)
{
    print "Yes, the answer is above 7 but below 78";
} 
else 
{
    print"that's not correct";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, use PHPs `&&` (and) to combine logic.

As an alternate to `if/else` methods listed here, you can use PHP's [ternary operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Something like this:

```php
echo ($value1<78 && $value1>7)
    ? "Yes, the answer is above 7 but below 78."
    : "That's not correct";
```